# Безопасность Apache / PHP

Tags: php, apache2, безопасность

Добрый день, на сайте есть уязвимости, например с момощью вот такого запроса:

```
"POST /local-bin/php/?-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -n
```

был создан и выполнен файл на сервере. Со стороны `php` - тут вроде все понятно - переопределяются директивы, а потом загружай файл и выполняй. 
Непонятно, почему веб-сервер позволил переопределить эти директивы через обычный http запрос на `/local-bin/php/?...` ?

Как предотвратить?

Спасибо.

Comment: Первый раз вижу, чтобы выполнение php делали доступным извне. Зачем?

Comment: Так настроил начинающий админ, возможно по незнанию, если знаете, подскажите, как это отключить на сервере. Спасибо.

Comment: Тем временем уже в ответе написали. Стоит поискать другие способы запуска PHP, например, тот же mod_php

Answer (score 3):

Это дырка в CGI, не PHP.
Тем не менее, для РНР была выпущена заплатка еще три года назад.

http://habrahabr.ru/post/143331/

Чтобы починить, лучше всего не запускать РНР в режиме CGI, поскольку это самый неэффективный способ запуска.
Либо обновить версию PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Обновить php мы не можем т.к. половина сайта пока работает на php 5.2, поэтому и запускаем php в режиме CGI.
С mod_php нужно запускать несколько  процессов апача, а у нас слабый сервак.

В итоге помогли следующие решения:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.force-redirect.php
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46566/protect-against-post-cgi-bin-php-attacks